# How can I know if an app is compatible with Android GO

Tags: android, android-8.1-oreo

I need to test if my app is compatible with the Android system Oreo GO. The problem is I don't have devices to test this one, as it seems very specific (created to run in low quality machines).

Anyway, I know Google allows the developer to prohibit the use of their app in this system. Is there any way to check this up? How did you do It?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to check the compatibility for now. For example, no emulator with Go edition is available. What can you do is -- 
Simply fire up Android Studio and set up an Android Studio emulator image at API level 19, then reduce the RAM size to 512MB and lower the JVM heap size. This should suffice as a testing environment until Google supplies official images to be launched within the Android Studio emulator.